# White pixels showing for div with corner radius

Tags: html, css, border, rounded-corners

I have two input fields in a form on my website. I have designed them to have only the `bottom-border` and applied the following other css:

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
}

.loginTextField {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    outline: none;
}
```

The text fields look like this, in HTML: (Also note, there is no div with the same size behind the text field.)

```
<input type="email" class="loginTextField" id="loginEmail">
```

Currently, even though only the bottom border is set, Safari renders the text fields the following way - notice the top corners having those white pixels:

[image: Current result in Safari]

[image]
*(it's easier to see on this one)*

Chrome, on the other hand, renders them as desired:

[image: Desired result and current in Chrome]

I know, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16938437/3397217) has been asked before. However, none of the proposed solutions work for me.

I have already tried doing something like:

```
border: 0 solid transparent;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
```

and:

```
border-top: 0 solid transparent;
border-right: 0 solid transparent;
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
```

...without any luck.

I did notice, however, that changing the `bottom-border-color` to, say, green, also changes those extra pixels to that color.

Check out this working [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zkhhwb68/).

Is there a way to have Safari not render those white pixels?

Comment: A hacky way of doing it - but instead of using transparent, you could set it to whatever background colour you're using?

Comment: That'd be `background: #35425A`. That doesn't change anything, though.

Comment: It still shows the white border? odd!

Comment: try using box-sizing property.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar, box-sizing doesn't affect it in any way unfortunately. Any other idea? Did you have a chance to check out the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I've added `box-shadow: inset 10px 10px #000;` in parent element

Before:
[image: before]

After:
[image: after]

Comment: From the screenshot it seems like the white corners are still there, just less visible...