# Border-radius and box shadow bug

Tags: html, css

I have a div with this styles:

```css
.example {
  margin: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: white 0px 0px 0pt 8pt, #033354 0px 0px 0pt 11pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
</div>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid those little lines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [White corner showing on black box with Border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938437/white-corner-showing-on-black-box-with-border-radius)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `background-color` as `white` will fix the issue.

```css
.example {
  margin: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: white 0px 0px 0pt 8pt, #033354 0px 0px 0pt 11pt;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you actually need, but if you need a rounded frame, here's my solution:

```
.example{
  margin: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.example:before {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% + 20px);
    height: calc(100% + 20px);
    border: 3px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    content: '';
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I used a :before pseudo-element to work as the frame (in some distance from the element itself). The frame adapts to the size of the .example element and doesn't react to mouse events so you can click whatever you have within .example :)