# White corners after border-radius

Tags: html, css

I want to create a card (that is an image and an overlay). The card should be with `border-radius`. Unfortunately, when I add it in conjunction with `overflow-y: hidden`, it creates some white pixels on the corners.

I have the following HTML structure and CSS code:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 80rem;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.works__column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.size {
  --size: 0;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
}

.work {
  display: grid;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

.work__preview,
.work__overlay {
  grid-area: 1 / 2;
}

.work__preview img {
  --size: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1.4;
}

.work__overlay {
  align-self: end;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.work__title {
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: var(--white);
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border-start-end-radius: .5rem;
  background-color: var(--steel-gray);
}

.work__icon {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-self: center;
  margin-bottom: .125rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="works">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="works__column">
      <div class="works__work work">
        <div class="work__preview">
          <img class="size" alt="Sports Elements" src="images/works/1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="work__overlay">
          <h3 class="work__title">
            Portier - The ultimate templates & components library.
          </h3>
          <div class="work__icon icon">0</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="works__work work">
        <div class="work__preview">
          <img class="size" alt="The Coporate" src="images/works/2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="work__overlay">
          <h3 class="work__title">
            The Coporate - Card for Indian Startups
          </h3>
          <div class="work__icon icon">1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="works__work work">
        <div class="work__preview">
          <img class="size" alt="App Interface" src="images/works/3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="work__overlay">
          <h3 class="work__title">
            Components Web App Interface
          </h3>
          <div class="work__icon icon">2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**You can see the problem in these images**: [image: Responsive mode]
[image: Zoom]

However, the last card works as expected. I don't know the reason.
[image]

I think the problem is that I applied `aspect-ratio` with `height: 100%` on `work__preview img`. This is required because the parent has a greater hight and the overlay starts to hang from the image.

Comment: Did you try those solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938437/white-corner-showing-on-black-box-with-border-radius?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [White corner showing on black box with Border-radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938437/white-corner-showing-on-black-box-with-border-radius)

Comment: Yes, I've seen this thread. Unfortunately, it doesn't help with solving my problem. I've tried to set border-radius for both parent and child (smaller for child as advised) blocks. I even tried to set it for image and for title - the last was a little bit better, but still there were white pixels (they were less visible).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the edges are from an underlying container which by default would have a white background; set the containers background to be transparent.

```
background-color: transparent;
```